# Использование регулярных выражений в Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть предложение:"Я родился 02.08.1996. А мой брат 09.03.2000". Если строка содержит число, месяц и год - нужно вернуть true; если нет - то false.
Вот мой код. В регулярных выражениях я очень слаб. Что нужно исправить в второй строке?

```
public static void date(String s) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/([0-2]\\d|3[01])\\.(0\\d|1[012])\\.(\\d{4})/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    boolean b = m.matches();
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум, в Вашем коде проблема в том, что Вам нужно проверить, **содержится** ли в одной строке другая строка (соответствующая заданному регулярному выражению), Вы же, вызывая метод `matches()`, проверяете **равенство** строк.

Я бы реализовал это вот так:

```
String s = "Я родился 02.08.1996. А мой брат 09.03.2000";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\d]{2}.[\\d]{2}.[\\d]{4}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
boolean b = m.find();
System.out.println(b);
```

**UPD**. Подробнее про саму регулярку`[\\d]{2}.[\\d]{2}.[\\d]{4}`:

- `[\\d]{2}` – два цифровых символа;
- `.` – точка;
- `[\\d]{2}` – два цифровых символа;
- `.` – точка;
- `[\\d]{4}` – четыре цифровых символа.

**UPD 2**. Регулярка для проверки дат формата `DD.MM.YYYY`:

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]).(0?[1-9]|1[012]).\d{4}$
```

Comment: А можешь объяснить конструкцию построен

Comment: @ВладКеся, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: А если я хочу поставить ограничение например на количество месяцев то мне нужно его записывать в эту часть [\\d]{2}

Comment: @ВладКеся, Какое именно ограничение?

Comment: @posr_zeew, Ну смотри например пользователь вводит что он родился 37.14.2000. Просто я думаю имеет смысл делать такую проверку

Comment: @ВладКеся, Добавил в ответ.

Comment: спасибо буду дома разберу что бы понимать что написано